# Zabbix and apache2 conf

Tags: server, apache2, php, zabbix

I'm trying to install Zabbix on Ubuntu Server 16.

I've followed  all the instructions here:

https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=3.4&os_distribution=ubuntu&os_version=xenial&db=PostgreSQL

but, I'm not able to find the apache configuration for zabbit, as described in the last point, in order to set the right **date.timezone**. Infact I'm able to run http://my_ip/zabbix web interface, but on the second step, Check of pre-requisites, I get the following error: Time zone for PHP is not set (configuration parameter "date.timezone"). Is the only fail in the pre-requisites.

The file */etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf* doesn't exist and I don't know how to set the following

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
# php_value date.timezone Europe/Riga
```

in the apache2.conf

Any suggestion on how and where to set the above value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue  on Ubuntu 14.04.4 and I have the set the values in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` as below.

You can also edit `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/zabbix.conf` which is simlink to `/etc/zabbix/apache.conf`:

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
php_value date.timezone America/Denver
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you would need to create the file with an editor ...

```
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf
```

(you also use `nano` or another editor) and then insert the options you listed. After the empty file is show type an "i" to insert new lines and then copy/paste below settings. And then `esc`, w, q to exit edit mode, save (w) and quit (q):

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
# php_value date.timezone Europe/Riga
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems file paths tend to change a lot over the years, and documentation doesn't stay up-to-date. Even the currently accepted answer here doesn't seem to be right anymore (though I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 now).

Today, the file you need to edit is `/etc/apache2/conf-available/zabbix-frontend-php.conf`. And the install instructions don't mention this, but you'll need to create a symlink to the `conf-enabled` directory, like so:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/zabbix-frontend-php.conf \
    /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/zabbix-frontend-php.conf
```

Also, nowadays there are *two* identical lines in this file that you need to uncomment and edit. Don't just edit the first one you see.

Answer (score 0):

Current install of Zabbix 5.0.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. The paths and files have changed.

Edit the /etc/zabbix/apache.conf and make sure you uncomment *both* instances of the php_value date.timezone variable.